# Areca palm silver leaves and dying

Tags: palm

my lovely Areca palm is not very happy.

It has **silver patches** on its leaves and is drying out and dying. There is no sign of bugs just silver on the leaves that does not wipe off.

Any idea what it is or what I can do please? Thank you.
[image][image]

Comment: Hi Caroline, can you add a picture of the top and the underside of a leaf?

Comment: Thanks - please see attached the top and underside of the same leaf. Thank you.